# How to remove the ' for Cstr(combox1.value)

Tags: vba, excel

I use this to change the combox value in string type and paste on cells.

```
  cells(i,1)=Cstr(combox1.value)
```

On Excel column A ,I have set the datatype as String .

For example , I input ``` 017``123 ``` `098` `065`

However , i find that the exact value put on cells(i,1) is `'017` `'098` `'056` `123` .
The code starting with `0` contains `'` at the beginning .

*** Any way to improve my code without appearing the `'` on exact cells ,for those codes starting with `0`    ***

Comment: The `'` that you are seeing is probably not part of the cell contents.  For instance, if you write a formula in cell B1 which says `=LEN(A1)`, you will undoubtedly find that it says there are 3 characters in cell A1 (i.e. `017`) rather than 4 (which is what you would get if cell A1 actually contains `'017`).  The `'` is just telling Excel to treat the field as a text string rather than as a number.  (It actually becomes annoying if you want a cell to contain `'abc'` because you have to type in `''abc'` instead.)

Comment: @YowE3K  Do u mean that this problem cannot be fixed and it is reasonable ?

Comment: I have added an "answer" to give a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'` is probably a formatting character, which is a hangover from Lotus 1-2-3 where we used a leading `'` to signify left-aligned and a leading `"` to signify right-aligned.  (I think I remember that correctly.)

If it is just the formatting character (if it is, it won't be included in the character count returned by LEN) then you can safely just ignore it.

If you want to get rid of it for aesthetic reasons, you will need to delete the current contents of the cell, format the cell as General format, then format the cell as Text format, then insert new values into the cell.

Note: You can't just format the cell as Text, delete the contents, then insert a new value.  The `'` will still appear in that situation.  The step to change it to General format, if it isn't already in that format, is important!  (Maybe setting it to some other non-Text format will work just as well as setting it to General, but I know that General will work.)

Luckily, a `.Clear` will delete the contents of the cell **and** set the format back to General, so programatically we can do two things at once.

I therefore believe the following code should do what you want:

```
    Cells(i, 1).Clear
    Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
    Cells(i, 1).Value = combox1.Value
```

The first line is there simply to get rid of the issue that currently exists.  If you were working with a completely new workbook, it wouldn't be needed.

Comment: i tried .it works . But as it clears the original cell format `.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter` is added after `Cells(i, 1).Clear` . Btw , would you explain more why `CStr` doesn't work and what is the difference between `CStr` and your method . thanks

Comment: `CStr` simply converts values of varying types to a string.  So `CStr(4.56)` would create a string of `4.56`.  As the result of your operation was a string of `017`, I can only assume that `combox1.Value` is already a string of `017`.  (If combox1.Value was the number 17, `CStr(combox1.Value)` would be `17`.)  So I don't think the use of CStr is anything to do with the issue you were having.

Answer (score 1):

convert the cell's number format to `Text` before setting numeric values.

```
cells(i,1).NumberFormat = "@"
cells(i,1)=combox1.value
```

Comment: do u mean I have no need to add `cells(i,1)=Cstr(combox1.value)`

Comment: no need. once u set the cell format to text, what ever you put there after that, is just string/text.

Comment: not working . Now all codes :S26 ,S34, S23 ,059 ,023 contains `'` .

Comment: for my code , only those beginning with `0`  contain `'`